# StAX fails to signal END_ELEMENT event correctly

Tags: java, stax

I have a issue with StAX parser. If anyone has seen this before, and knows how to fix it it would be great.

The basic idea is this. I have XML files of the following kind:

```
....
<ContainedResourceList>
    <Resource> ... </Resource>
    <Resource> ... </Resource>
    ....
    <Resource> ... </Resource>
</ContainedResourceList>
<ContainedReleaseList>
    <Release>...</Release>
    <Release>...</Release>
    ....
    <Release>...</Release>
</ContainedReleaseList>
....
```

Now, when the XML tags are position EXACTLY like above everything works fine, StAX gives me Start Element and End Element events correctlly for each tag.

How ever I also have some files which are not nicely formatted, but instead look something like this:

```
....
<ContainedResourceList>
<Resource> ... </Resource>
    <Resource> ... </Resource>
    ....
    <Resource> ... </Resource></ContainedResourceList><ContainedReleaseList><Release>...</Release>
<Release>...</Release>
    ....
    <Release>...</Release>
</ContainedReleaseList>
....
```

The exact some kind of tags oragnisation, the only difference is indentation and carriage returns after and end tag. now when I parse this kind of file, even though the `</ContainedResourceList>` end tag is in the middle of the file, StAX will not signal it's ending properly. Instead it will make an END tag event for `</ContainedResourceList>` all the way at the end of the file, AFTER `</ContainedReleaseList>`.

Also, If I take such an XML file and manually add carriage returns after each end tag (pretty much make it look like the first example) now StAX will parse it correctly, each end tag is signaled where it should.

I've tried this with Woodstox StAX implementation version 4.1.1 and 4.1.2 as well as StAX refference implementation 1.0.2, the behaviour is exactlly the same. This makes me think that it's not a bug per-se, but just something I might be missing.

For refference, the code I use to parse the file is something like this:

```
XMLInputFactory2 xmlInputFactory = (XMLInputFactory2) XMLInputFactory2.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(xmlFile);
while(reader.hasNext()) {

    staxParseEventType = reader.next();

    switch(staxParseEventType) {
    case START_ELEMENT: {
        //do something on the element if it's local name is whatever
        break;
    }
    case END_ELEMENT: {
        //do something at the end of this element if it's name is whatever
        break;
    }
    case END_DOCUMENT: {
        //do something when document ends
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

My question is the, is this behaviour normal? Is it a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce your problem - but couldn't :( I used the default XMLStreamReader implementation AND woodstox 4.1.2 with nicely and not-so-nicely formatted xml - both gave me the exact same result. Could you please provide full xmls? More code? Are there any special environment settings? How about the file encoding?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, unfortunatelly I can't provide the exact XML file as it's kind of sensitive information. I should mention that it doens't happend with ANY AND ALL files that are formatted as descirbed, just with some of them. This is very weird, the file is fine, as proof being the fact that other XML tools find the tags ok, and even STAX finds them ok once I add some CRs after certain tags.

Comment: Hi Andrei, I am afraid I can't help you out here...just some points for you to have a look at: From your snippet, I guess you use Files - if so, make sure to read in the correct encoding (and doublecheck it again). I ran into lots of problems due to encoding issues. Also, check the properties of the XMLInputFactory (IS_COALESCING, IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, etc). Maybe try to setup a blank environment and try with the default StAX-implementation. If it works, check your environment settings - maybe there is something. Sorry and good luck!

Comment: Thankx, I'll check those things.